# How to apply a bivariate function over the cross combination of two vectors to get a matrix in R?

Tags: r

Say I have two vectors:

```
a <- 1:4
b <- 1:2
```

and a bivariate function:

```
f <- function(x,y) x**y
```

I would like to get a simple and efficient way (a one-liner?) to get (for this specific example):

```
[,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    3    9
[4,]    4   16
```

I can do:

```
res <- matrix(nrow=length(a), ncol=length(b))
for (i in 1:length(b)){
  res[,i] <- mapply(f, a , b[i])
}
```

but I want to avoid loops.

Comment: is it ok if your result is a data.frame and not a matrix ?

Comment: What would be your solution returning a dataframe @OrhanYazar?

Comment: `data.frame(a*b[1],a*b[2])` but if you need to do it in larger arrays the solution of Leo is far better @vwrobel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `lapply` over one of the vectors, while setting the other as constant. Then `cbind()` the list with `do.call()`:

```
test <- do.call(cbind, lapply(b, function(x) a**x))

> test
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    1
[2,]    2    4
[3,]    3    9
[4,]    4   16
```